# boost asio timer : run 2 timers

Tags: c++, boost, timer

I try to run a asynchronous timer and a synchronous timer :

Here is my code :

```
boost::asio::io_service io;

boost::asio::steady_timer t1(io);
boost::asio::steady_timer t2(io);

void callback(boost::system::error_code const&)
{
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    t1.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
    t1.async_wait(&callback);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{


    t1.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
    t1.async_wait(&callback);

    io.run();

    t2.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(5));

    t2.wait();

    io.run();

    std::cout << "finish" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would like `foo` to printed 5 times, and `finish` printed.
In this code, `foo` is printed every 1 second and `finish` is never reached.

How to achieve what I want ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation of `io_service::run`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html):

> The run() function blocks until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched, or until the io_service has been stopped.

Since `run` blocks until there are no more handlers to be dispatched, it will block until `callback` has finished. However, `callback` registers another `callback` handler and `run` will keep blocking until it's finished... ad infinitum

If you want the callback to repeat only five times, then you need to not schedule a new callback after the fifth time.You can use a simple counter and a branch for that.

Answer (score 0):

As said in user2079303's answer, your first `io.run()` call never returns since `callback` registers itself.

To achieve what you want to do, you can just modify your `callback` function as followed:

```
void callback(boost::system::error_code const&)
{
  static int    i = 0;

  std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
  t1.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
  if (++i < 5) {
    t1.async_wait(&callback);
  } else {
    i = 0; // Reset i if you want to reuse callback later with the same behaviour
  }
}
```